# Websphere server - Failed to create temporary file

Tags: websphere

When deploying or starting websphere aplication server this happens :

**Failed to create temporary file.**
A nested strategy will be used, but this usually slows performance dramatically.
[2/17/12 14:46:38:554 CET] 000004b8 wtp           W org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.impl.CommonarchiveFactoryImpl createNestedLoadStrategy Could not create temp file for base URI [ com/test/VAD_DTO_Types_v20120109_JAXB_Java_source.zip ] and temporary directory [ C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv02\wstemp\appdepl13586c79ef3 ]; creating nested strategy

Could you provide me any reasons for this behaviour ? I googled for this message but without any direct solution...

Comment: Could this be related to access rights on the temp folder ? And is there enough space available on disk ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using WebSphere 7.0.0.0 there seems to be an issue in the ibmasyncrsp application. Applying patch to 7.0.0.1 or greater should fix the issue

see http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PK72301 for more details on this.

Comment: I still get this message. I'm using WAS 7.0.0.21.

Comment: @steve.hanson 7.0.0.23 should fix that issue as pointed out here: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PM48503 However I still have that problem

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I had the same problem and thought I would post my solution.  For me it was because I had insufficient disk space on /usr on my AIX box.  If you're running Linux or Unix, try increasing the size of your filesystem and try again.  (For example, to increase the size of /usr by 1 gb, run `chfs -a size=+1G /usr`.)